# Asynchronous state with input in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, state

I've got a problem with my state which is late everytime. The app consists in checking your vocabulary in english or french but I've caught up with the issue that the state currentAnswer is always late by one character and the sentence 'Correct !' displays only if I write one more character. I can't fix the problem. All I can guess is that the state is not asynchronous but I can't make it asynchronous. Any Idea ?

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      words: [
        {
          francais: 'bonjour',
          anglais: 'hello',
        },
        {
          francais: 'manger',
          anglais: 'eat',
        },
        {
          francais: 'avoir',
          anglais: 'have',
        },
        {
          francais: 'faire',
          anglais: 'do',
        },
        {
          francais: 'jouer',
          anglais: 'play',
        }
    ],
    key: -1.4,
    currentWord: '',
    currentAnswer: '',
    correctAnswer: false,
    giveUp: false,
    currentScore: 0,
    scoreTotal: 0
    }
  }

  generateWord = () => {
    let index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (this.state.words.length + 1))
    if(index === this.state.key) {
      this.generateWord()
    }
    this.setState({currentWord: this.state.words[index]})
    this.setState({key: index})
  }

  validate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const answer = e.target.value
    this.setState({ currentAnswer: answer})
    if (this.state.currentAnswer === this.state.currentWord.anglais) {
      this.setState({correctAnswer : true})
    }
  }

  showCorrection = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({giveUp: true})
    this.setState({scoreTotal: this.state.scoreTotal + 1})
  }

  nextWord = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({currentAnswer: ''})
    this.setState({ giveUp: false })
    this.setState({ correctAnswer: false })
    this.generateWord()
    if(this.state.correctAnswer) {
      this.setState({currentScore: this.state.currentScore + 1})
      this.setState({scoreTotal: this.state.scoreTotal + 1})
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.generateWord()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <p>Score: {this.state.currentScore}/{this.state.scoreTotal}</p>
        <h2 style={{
          color: "midnightblue",
          fontSize: "50px"
        }}>{this.state.currentWord?.francais}</h2> 
        <form action="">
          <input onChange={this.validate} value={this.state.currentAnswer} type="text" placeholder="Entrez la traduction anglaise"/>
          <button className="validation" onClick={this.showCorrection}>Give up</button>
          <button className="validation" onClick={this.nextWord}>Next</button>
        </form>      
        {this.state.correctAnswer ? <p>Correct !</p> : this.state.giveUp ? <p>La bonne réponse était: {this.state.currentWord?.anglais}</p>: ''}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed `setState()` method is async and will not always update immediately.
But to fix your validation, simply compare the word to the current input instead of the current answer in state :

```
validate = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const answer = e.target.value
    this.setState({ currentAnswer: answer})
    if (answer === this.state.currentWord.anglais) {
      this.setState({correctAnswer : true})
    }
  }
```